# how to change os.system() call to subprocess.call() for below code

Tags: python-2.7

Need to know how i can convert below code from os.system to subprocess.call with shell=False

Code to be modified:

```
command1="ls -lrt"
command2="cat file.txt"
cucDBServiceStartRC =  os.WEXITSTATUS(os.system(command1 + " && " + command2))
if(cucDBServiceStartRC!=0);
    do something..
```

I Tried:

```
command1="ls -lrt"
command2="cat file.txt"
cucDBServiceStartRC = os.WEXITSTATUS(subprocess.call(shlex.split(command1 + " && " + command2),shell=False))
if(cucDBServiceStartRC!=0);
    do something..
```

But command fails to compile.

Note: I want to do it with `shell=False`, so i need workaround for && ( used in above code for `os.system`) to be used in subprocess to run 2 commands at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&` is a shell operator. If you want to run two programs without a shell inbetween, you need to run `subprocess.call` twice:

```
returnCode = subprocess.call(shlex.split(command1), shell=False);
if returnCode == 0:
    returnCode = subprocess.call(shlex.split(command2), shell=False);
// Do whatever with returnCode. A value of 0 means either command failed.
```

It would be better, not to split the command line with `shlex.split`. Instead keep the executable name separate from the arguments from the beginning. Otherwise, if the user can influence the content of `command1` or `command2`, you will have the same security concerns as with `shell=True`.